# DB High availability through jdbc connection proxy?

Tags: jdbc, replication, transactional-replication

I need to have a high availability database system but I can't do it through database cluster or master/slave. I need a jdbc proxy that knows to update multiple data source for a single update statement. I found HA-JDBC project http://ha-jdbc.github.com/ that does that but I was wondering if there are similar or better library than HA-JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

You can see other project around HA features: Sequoia/C-JDBC (http://c-jdbc.ow2.org).

But some links on page are broken ;(